# convert c char* to python bytes with ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm trying to convert c char* to python bytes with ctypes

**C code**

```
char* hello() {
    return "hello"
}
```

**Python code**

```py
import ctypes
my_c = ctypes.CDLL(myclib)
my_c.hello()
```

However, instead of returning "hello", it returns a long int:
`278419308`

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [ctypes documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), in particular [Return types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#return-types):

> **Return Types**
>
> By default functions are assumed to return the C int type. Other return types can be specified by setting the `restype` attribute of the function object.

So:

```py
import ctypes
my_c = ctypes.CDLL(myclib)
my_c.hello.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
print(my_c.hello())
```

Further reading: [Specifying the required argument types (function prototypes)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes)

Set  `.argtypes` and `.restype` correctly for *every* function call.  Don't make `ctypes` assume the argument and return types and it will better error check.